# Second orthogonality relation for compact groups

Tags: representation-theory, locally-compact-groups

On a *finite group* $G$, we have the **second orthogonality relation**
$$\sum_{\chi\text{ irred.}} \chi(g)\overline{\chi(h)}=\begin{cases}|C_G(g)|&g=h\\0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
for $g,h\in G$, where $|C_G(g)|$ is the size of the conjugacy class of $G$.

If $G$ is a **compact group** with Haar measure $\mu$, the first orthogonality relation generalizes:
$$\int_G \chi_1(g)\overline{\chi_2(g)} d\mu(g)=\begin{cases}|G|&\chi_1\cong\chi_2\\0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
for $\chi_1,\chi_2$ irreducible characters of $G$. On the other hand, it is not clear what happens about the second orthogonality relation. Does it generalize as well ? Can we compute the integral
$$\int_{\chi\in\widehat G\text{ irred}} \chi(g)\overline{\chi(h)} dg$$
over the dual group $\widehat G$ (with respect to its Haar measure as a locally compact group) ?
In particular, it is not clear what $|C_G(g)|$ would become.

Comment: In the first orthogonality relation, you are mixing up the summation for finite groups with the integral based on normalized Haar measure. (The integral needs to be $1$ not $|G|$.) In any case, the character group of $G$ is the dual group of the abelianization $G^{\rm ab}$, so is "collapsed." The unitary dual $G^{\wedge}$ is a discrete collection of (isomorphism classes of) unitary irreducible representations with the Plancherel measure, and is in general not a group. (Pontryagin duality generalizes to Tannaka-Krein duality.)